# Issue when building QT 5.15.2 (w/ QTWebEngine) with cross compile

Tags: linux, qt, raspberry-pi, qt5

Over the last few weeks, I've spent a significant amount of effort trying to simplify and streamline the build of QT for the Raspberry Pi, and I'm *very* close to the finishing line.

In short, I've [dockerized](https://github.com/Screenly/screenly-ose/blob/experimental/webview/Dockerfile) and [scripted](https://github.com/Screenly/screenly-ose/blob/experimental/webview/build_qt5.sh) the whole build process to ensure that we can build images for Pi 1 - Pi 4 in an easy and reproducible way without requiring a physical Raspberry Pi.

I've been able to get hardware acceleration to be detected for Pi 3 and Pi 4 as part of the `./configure` step of QT, and been able to build QT Base (and a few other depencencies) just fine. However, I'm losing my mind on this last error as part of the error.

The error is *very* similar to what Enrico Zini descibes [here](https://www.enricozini.org/blog/2020/qt5/build-qt5-cross-builder-with-raspbian-sysroot-compiling-with-the-sysroot-continued/), however his workaround `dpkg --purge libraspberrypi-dev`  (or rather [Andreas Gruber](http://www.gruber.info/)'s) won't cut it as it will disable hardware acceleration, which I need.

The error appears in the very late stage of the QTWebEngine build:

```
[...]
[20312/20662] ccache /src/gcc-linaro-7.4.1-2019.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -MMD -MF obj/QtWebEngineCore/gl_surface_qt.o.d -DCHROMIUM_VERSION=\"83.0.4103.122\" -DUSE_UDEV -DUSE_AURA=1 -DUSE_NSS_CERTS=1 -DUSE_OZONE=1 -DOFFICIAL_BUILD -DTOOLKIT_QT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -DNO_UNWIND_TABLES -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -DCR_SYSROOT_HASH=3fcc1d4e44127006318371002a0f421a4fde2ab4 -DNDEBUG -DNVALGRIND -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=0 -DQT_NO_LINKED_LIST -DQT_NO_KEYWORDS -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQ_FORWARD_DECLARE_OBJC_CLASS=QT_FORWARD_DECLARE_CLASS -DQTWEBENGINECORE_VERSION_STR=\"5.15.2\" -DQTWEBENGINEPROCESS_NAME=\"QtWebEngineProcess\" -DBUILDING_CHROMIUM -DQTWEBENGINE_EMBEDDED_SWITCHES -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_QMLMODELS_LIB -DQT_WEBCHANNEL_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_WEBENGINECOREHEADERS_LIB -DVK_NO_PROTOTYPES -DUSE_EGL -DU_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE=0 -DU_ENABLE_DYLOAD=0 -DUSE_CHROMIUM_ICU=1 -DU_ENABLE_TRACING=1 -DU_ENABLE_RESOURCE_TRACING=0 -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DICU_UTIL_DATA_IMPL=ICU_UTIL_DATA_FILE -DUCHAR_TYPE=uint16_t -DGOOGLE_PROTOBUF_NO_RTTI -DGOOGLE_PROTOBUF_NO_STATIC_INITIALIZER -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DWEBRTC_NON_STATIC_TRACE_EVENT_HANDLERS=0 -DWEBRTC_CHROMIUM_BUILD -DWEBRTC_POSIX -DWEBRTC_LINUX -DABSL_ALLOCATOR_NOTHROW=1 -DWEBRTC_USE_BUILTIN_ISAC_FIX=1 -DWEBRTC_USE_BUILTIN_ISAC_FLOAT=0 -DHAVE_SCTP -DNO_MAIN_THREAD_WRAPPING -DSK_CODEC_DECODES_PNG -DSK_CODEC_DECODES_WEBP -DSK_ENCODE_PNG -DSK_ENCODE_WEBP -DSK_USER_CONFIG_HEADER=\"../../skia/config/SkUserConfig.h\" -DSK_GL -DSK_CODEC_DECODES_JPEG -DSK_ENCODE_JPEG -DSK_USE_LIBGIFCODEC -DSK_VULKAN_HEADER=\"../../skia/config/SkVulkanConfig.h\" -DSK_VULKAN=1 -DSK_SUPPORT_GPU=1 -DSK_GPU_WORKAROUNDS_HEADER=\"gpu/config/gpu_driver_bug_workaround_autogen.h\" -DVK_NO_PROTOTYPES -DCRASHPAD_ZLIB_SOURCE_EXTERNAL -DUSE_SYSTEM_ZLIB=1 -DLEVELDB_PLATFORM_CHROMIUM=1 -DLEVELDB_PLATFORM_CHROMIUM=1 -DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/skia/config -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/boringssl/src/include -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/skia/include/core -Igen -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium -I/src/qt5/qtwebengine/src/core -I/src/qt5/qtwebengine/src/core/api -I/src/qt5/qtdeclarative/include/QtQuick/5.15.2 -I/src/qt5/qtdeclarative/include/QtQuick/5.15.2/QtQuick -I/src/pi3/qtdeclarative/include/QtQuick/5.15.2 -I/src/pi3/qtdeclarative/include/QtQuick/5.15.2/QtQuick -I/src/qt5/qtbase/include/QtGui/5.15.2 -I/src/qt5/qtbase/include/QtGui/5.15.2/QtGui -I/src/pi3/qtbase/include/QtGui/5.15.2 -I/src/pi3/qtbase/include/QtGui/5.15.2/QtGui -I/src/qt5/qtdeclarative/include -I/src/qt5/qtdeclarative/include/QtQuick -I/src/pi3/qtdeclarative/include -I/src/pi3/qtdeclarative/include/QtQuick -I/src/qt5/qtbase/include -I/src/qt5/qtbase/include/QtGui -I/src/pi3/qtbase/include -I/src/pi3/qtbase/include/QtGui -I/src/qt5/qtdeclarative/include/QtQmlModels/5.15.2 -I/src/qt5/qtdeclarative/include/QtQmlModels/5.15.2/QtQmlModels -I/src/pi3/qtdeclarative/include/QtQmlModels/5.15.2 -I/src/pi3/qtdeclarative/include/QtQmlModels/5.15.2/QtQmlModels -I/src/qt5/qtdeclarative/include/QtQml/5.15.2 -I/src/qt5/qtdeclarative/include/QtQml/5.15.2/QtQml -I/src/pi3/qtdeclarative/include/QtQml/5.15.2 -I/src/pi3/qtdeclarative/include/QtQml/5.15.2/QtQml -I/src/qt5/qtbase/include/QtCore/5.15.2 -I/src/qt5/qtbase/include/QtCore/5.15.2/QtCore -I/src/pi3/qtbase/include/QtCore/5.15.2 -I/src/pi3/qtbase/include/QtCore/5.15.2/QtCore -I/src/qt5/qtdeclarative/include/QtQmlModels -I/src/pi3/qtdeclarative/include/QtQmlModels -I/src/qt5/qtwebchannel/include -I/src/qt5/qtwebchannel/include/QtWebChannel -I/src/pi3/qtwebchannel/include -I/src/pi3/qtwebchannel/include/QtWebChannel -I/src/qt5/qtdeclarative/include/QtQml -I/src/pi3/qtdeclarative/include/QtQml -I/src/qt5/qtbase/include/QtNetwork -I/src/pi3/qtbase/include/QtNetwork -I/src/qt5/qtbase/include/QtCore -I/src/pi3/qtbase/include/QtCore -I/src/qt5/qtwebengine/include -I/src/qt5/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineCore -I/src/qt5/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineCore/5.15.2 -I/src/qt5/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineCore/5.15.2/QtWebEngineCore -I/src/pi3/qtwebengine/include -I/src/pi3/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineCore -I/src/pi3/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineCore/5.15.2 -I/src/pi3/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineCore/5.15.2/QtWebEngineCore -I.moc -I/opt/vc/include -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vmcs_host/linux -Igen/.moc -I/src/qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/devices/linux-rasp-pi3-g++ -Igen -Igen -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/perfetto/include -Igen/third_party/perfetto/build_config -Igen/third_party/perfetto -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/libyuv/include -Igen -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/jsoncpp/source/include -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/jsoncpp/generated -Igen -Igen -Igen/third_party/dawn/src/include -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/dawn/src/include -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/khronos -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/gpu -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/vulkan/include -Igen -Igen -Igen -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/boringssl/src/include -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/ced/src -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/icu/source/common -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/icu/source/i18n -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/protobuf/src -Igen/protoc_out -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/protobuf/src -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/webrtc_overrides -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/webrtc -Igen/third_party/webrtc -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/abseil-cpp -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/skia -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/libgifcodec -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/vulkan/include -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/skia/third_party/vulkanmemoryallocator -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/vulkan/include -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/crashpad/crashpad -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/crashpad/crashpad/compat/non_mac -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/crashpad/crashpad/compat/linux -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/crashpad/crashpad/compat/non_win -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/libwebm/source -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/leveldatabase -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/leveldatabase/src -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/leveldatabase/src/include -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/v8/include -Igen/v8/include -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/mesa_headers -fno-strict-aliasing --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fstack-protector -fno-unwind-tables -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fPIC -pipe -pthread -march=armv8-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mtune=cortex-a53 -mfpu=neon -mthumb -Wall -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wno-psabi -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-deprecated-declarations -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-comments -Wno-packed-not-aligned -Wno-dangling-else -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -O2 -fno-ident -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -fvisibility=hidden -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a53 -mfpu=crypto-neon-fp-armv8 -mfloat-abi=hard --sysroot=/sysroot -O2 -fno-exceptions -Wall -Wextra -D_REENTRANT -I/sysroot/usr/include/nss -I/sysroot/usr/include/nspr -std=gnu++14 -Wno-narrowing -Wno-class-memaccess -Wno-attributes -Wno-class-memaccess -Wno-subobject-linkage -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-return-type -Wno-deprecated-copy -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti --sysroot=../../../../../../sysroot -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a53 -mfpu=crypto-neon-fp-armv8 -mfloat-abi=hard --sysroot=/sysroot -O2 -std=gnu++1y -fno-exceptions -Wall -Wextra -D_REENTRANT -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-deprecated-declarations -c /src/qt5/qtwebengine/src/core/ozone/gl_surface_qt.cpp -o obj/QtWebEngineCore/gl_surface_qt.o
FAILED: obj/QtWebEngineCore/gl_surface_qt.o
ccache /src/gcc-linaro-7.4.1-2019.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -MMD -MF obj/QtWebEngineCore/gl_surface_qt.o.d -DCHROMIUM_VERSION=\"83.0.4103.122\" -DUSE_UDEV -DUSE_AURA=1 -DUSE_NSS_CERTS=1 -DUSE_OZONE=1 -DOFFICIAL_BUILD -DTOOLKIT_QT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -DNO_UNWIND_TABLES -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -DCR_SYSROOT_HASH=3fcc1d4e44127006318371002a0f421a4fde2ab4 -DNDEBUG -DNVALGRIND -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=0 -DQT_NO_LINKED_LIST -DQT_NO_KEYWORDS -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQ_FORWARD_DECLARE_OBJC_CLASS=QT_FORWARD_DECLARE_CLASS -DQTWEBENGINECORE_VERSION_STR=\"5.15.2\" -DQTWEBENGINEPROCESS_NAME=\"QtWebEngineProcess\" -DBUILDING_CHROMIUM -DQTWEBENGINE_EMBEDDED_SWITCHES -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_QMLMODELS_LIB -DQT_WEBCHANNEL_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_WEBENGINECOREHEADERS_LIB -DVK_NO_PROTOTYPES -DUSE_EGL -DU_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE=0 -DU_ENABLE_DYLOAD=0 -DUSE_CHROMIUM_ICU=1 -DU_ENABLE_TRACING=1 -DU_ENABLE_RESOURCE_TRACING=0 -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DICU_UTIL_DATA_IMPL=ICU_UTIL_DATA_FILE -DUCHAR_TYPE=uint16_t -DGOOGLE_PROTOBUF_NO_RTTI -DGOOGLE_PROTOBUF_NO_STATIC_INITIALIZER -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DWEBRTC_NON_STATIC_TRACE_EVENT_HANDLERS=0 -DWEBRTC_CHROMIUM_BUILD -DWEBRTC_POSIX -DWEBRTC_LINUX -DABSL_ALLOCATOR_NOTHROW=1 -DWEBRTC_USE_BUILTIN_ISAC_FIX=1 -DWEBRTC_USE_BUILTIN_ISAC_FLOAT=0 -DHAVE_SCTP -DNO_MAIN_THREAD_WRAPPING -DSK_CODEC_DECODES_PNG -DSK_CODEC_DECODES_WEBP -DSK_ENCODE_PNG -DSK_ENCODE_WEBP -DSK_USER_CONFIG_HEADER=\"../../skia/config/SkUserConfig.h\" -DSK_GL -DSK_CODEC_DECODES_JPEG -DSK_ENCODE_JPEG -DSK_USE_LIBGIFCODEC -DSK_VULKAN_HEADER=\"../../skia/config/SkVulkanConfig.h\" -DSK_VULKAN=1 -DSK_SUPPORT_GPU=1 -DSK_GPU_WORKAROUNDS_HEADER=\"gpu/config/gpu_driver_bug_workaround_autogen.h\" -DVK_NO_PROTOTYPES -DCRASHPAD_ZLIB_SOURCE_EXTERNAL -DUSE_SYSTEM_ZLIB=1 -DLEVELDB_PLATFORM_CHROMIUM=1 -DLEVELDB_PLATFORM_CHROMIUM=1 -DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/skia/config -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/boringssl/src/include -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/skia/include/core -Igen -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium -I/src/qt5/qtwebengine/src/core -I/src/qt5/qtwebengine/src/core/api -I/src/qt5/qtdeclarative/include/QtQuick/5.15.2 -I/src/qt5/qtdeclarative/include/QtQuick/5.15.2/QtQuick -I/src/pi3/qtdeclarative/include/QtQuick/5.15.2 -I/src/pi3/qtdeclarative/include/QtQuick/5.15.2/QtQuick -I/src/qt5/qtbase/include/QtGui/5.15.2 -I/src/qt5/qtbase/include/QtGui/5.15.2/QtGui -I/src/pi3/qtbase/include/QtGui/5.15.2 -I/src/pi3/qtbase/include/QtGui/5.15.2/QtGui -I/src/qt5/qtdeclarative/include -I/src/qt5/qtdeclarative/include/QtQuick -I/src/pi3/qtdeclarative/include -I/src/pi3/qtdeclarative/include/QtQuick -I/src/qt5/qtbase/include -I/src/qt5/qtbase/include/QtGui -I/src/pi3/qtbase/include -I/src/pi3/qtbase/include/QtGui -I/src/qt5/qtdeclarative/include/QtQmlModels/5.15.2 -I/src/qt5/qtdeclarative/include/QtQmlModels/5.15.2/QtQmlModels -I/src/pi3/qtdeclarative/include/QtQmlModels/5.15.2 -I/src/pi3/qtdeclarative/include/QtQmlModels/5.15.2/QtQmlModels -I/src/qt5/qtdeclarative/include/QtQml/5.15.2 -I/src/qt5/qtdeclarative/include/QtQml/5.15.2/QtQml -I/src/pi3/qtdeclarative/include/QtQml/5.15.2 -I/src/pi3/qtdeclarative/include/QtQml/5.15.2/QtQml -I/src/qt5/qtbase/include/QtCore/5.15.2 -I/src/qt5/qtbase/include/QtCore/5.15.2/QtCore -I/src/pi3/qtbase/include/QtCore/5.15.2 -I/src/pi3/qtbase/include/QtCore/5.15.2/QtCore -I/src/qt5/qtdeclarative/include/QtQmlModels -I/src/pi3/qtdeclarative/include/QtQmlModels -I/src/qt5/qtwebchannel/include -I/src/qt5/qtwebchannel/include/QtWebChannel -I/src/pi3/qtwebchannel/include -I/src/pi3/qtwebchannel/include/QtWebChannel -I/src/qt5/qtdeclarative/include/QtQml -I/src/pi3/qtdeclarative/include/QtQml -I/src/qt5/qtbase/include/QtNetwork -I/src/pi3/qtbase/include/QtNetwork -I/src/qt5/qtbase/include/QtCore -I/src/pi3/qtbase/include/QtCore -I/src/qt5/qtwebengine/include -I/src/qt5/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineCore -I/src/qt5/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineCore/5.15.2 -I/src/qt5/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineCore/5.15.2/QtWebEngineCore -I/src/pi3/qtwebengine/include -I/src/pi3/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineCore -I/src/pi3/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineCore/5.15.2 -I/src/pi3/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineCore/5.15.2/QtWebEngineCore -I.moc -I/opt/vc/include -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vmcs_host/linux -Igen/.moc -I/src/qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/devices/linux-rasp-pi3-g++ -Igen -Igen -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/perfetto/include -Igen/third_party/perfetto/build_config -Igen/third_party/perfetto -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/libyuv/include -Igen -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/jsoncpp/source/include -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/jsoncpp/generated -Igen -Igen -Igen/third_party/dawn/src/include -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/dawn/src/include -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/khronos -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/gpu -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/vulkan/include -Igen -Igen -Igen -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/boringssl/src/include -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/ced/src -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/icu/source/common -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/icu/source/i18n -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/protobuf/src -Igen/protoc_out -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/protobuf/src -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/webrtc_overrides -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/webrtc -Igen/third_party/webrtc -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/abseil-cpp -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/skia -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/libgifcodec -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/vulkan/include -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/skia/third_party/vulkanmemoryallocator -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/vulkan/include -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/crashpad/crashpad -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/crashpad/crashpad/compat/non_mac -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/crashpad/crashpad/compat/linux -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/crashpad/crashpad/compat/non_win -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/libwebm/source -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/leveldatabase -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/leveldatabase/src -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/leveldatabase/src/include -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/v8/include -Igen/v8/include -I../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/mesa_headers -fno-strict-aliasing --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fstack-protector -fno-unwind-tables -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fPIC -pipe -pthread -march=armv8-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mtune=cortex-a53 -mfpu=neon -mthumb -Wall -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wno-psabi -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-deprecated-declarations -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-comments -Wno-packed-not-aligned -Wno-dangling-else -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -O2 -fno-ident -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -fvisibility=hidden -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a53 -mfpu=crypto-neon-fp-armv8 -mfloat-abi=hard --sysroot=/sysroot -O2 -fno-exceptions -Wall -Wextra -D_REENTRANT -I/sysroot/usr/include/nss -I/sysroot/usr/include/nspr -std=gnu++14 -Wno-narrowing -Wno-class-memaccess -Wno-attributes -Wno-class-memaccess -Wno-subobject-linkage -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-return-type -Wno-deprecated-copy -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti --sysroot=../../../../../../sysroot -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a53 -mfpu=crypto-neon-fp-armv8 -mfloat-abi=hard --sysroot=/sysroot -O2 -std=gnu++1y -fno-exceptions -Wall -Wextra -D_REENTRANT -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-deprecated-declarations -c /src/qt5/qtwebengine/src/core/ozone/gl_surface_qt.cpp -o obj/QtWebEngineCore/gl_surface_qt.o
In file included from ../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings.h:511:0,
                 from /src/qt5/qtwebengine/src/core/ozone/gl_surface_qt.cpp:57:
../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings_autogen_egl.h:201:5: error: 'EGLDeviceEXT' has not been declared
     EGLDeviceEXT* devices,
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings_autogen_egl.h:204:5: error: typedef 'gl::eglQueryDeviceStringEXTProc' is initialized (use decltype instead)
     EGLDeviceEXT device,
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings_autogen_egl.h:204:5: error: 'EGLDeviceEXT' was not declared in this scope
../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings_autogen_egl.h:205:12: error: expected primary-expression before 'name'
     EGLint name);
            ^~~~
../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings_autogen_egl.h:239:5: error: 'EGLSetBlobFuncANDROID' has not been declared
     EGLSetBlobFuncANDROID set,
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings_autogen_egl.h:240:5: error: 'EGLGetBlobFuncANDROID' has not been declared
     EGLGetBlobFuncANDROID get);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings_autogen_egl.h:371:3: error: 'eglQueryDeviceStringEXTProc' does not name a type; did you mean 'eglQueryDeviceStringEXT'?
   eglQueryDeviceStringEXTProc eglQueryDeviceStringEXTFn;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   eglQueryDeviceStringEXT
../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings_autogen_egl.h:567:43: error: 'EGLDeviceEXT' has not been declared
                                           EGLDeviceEXT* devices,
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings_autogen_egl.h:569:49: error: 'eglQueryDeviceStringEXTFn' declared as a 'virtual' field
   virtual const char* eglQueryDeviceStringEXTFn(EGLDeviceEXT device,
                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings_autogen_egl.h:569:23: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
   virtual const char* eglQueryDeviceStringEXTFn(EGLDeviceEXT device,
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings_autogen_egl.h:569:62: error: expected ')' before 'device'
   virtual const char* eglQueryDeviceStringEXTFn(EGLDeviceEXT device,
                                                              ^~~~~~
../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings_autogen_egl.h:599:46: error: 'EGLSetBlobFuncANDROID' has not been declared
                                              EGLSetBlobFuncANDROID set,
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings_autogen_egl.h:600:46: error: 'EGLGetBlobFuncANDROID' has not been declared
                                              EGLGetBlobFuncANDROID get) = 0;
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_egl_api_implementation.h:31:0,
                 from /src/qt5/qtwebengine/src/core/ozone/gl_surface_qt.cpp:71:
../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings_api_autogen_egl.h:164:33: error: 'EGLDeviceEXT' has not been declared
                                 EGLDeviceEXT* devices,
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings_api_autogen_egl.h:166:13: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
 const char* eglQueryDeviceStringEXTFn(EGLDeviceEXT device,
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings_api_autogen_egl.h:166:52: error: expected ')' before 'device'
 const char* eglQueryDeviceStringEXTFn(EGLDeviceEXT device,
                                                    ^~~~~~
../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings_api_autogen_egl.h:196:36: error: 'EGLSetBlobFuncANDROID' has not been declared
                                    EGLSetBlobFuncANDROID set,
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings_api_autogen_egl.h:197:36: error: 'EGLGetBlobFuncANDROID' has not been declared
                                    EGLGetBlobFuncANDROID get) override;
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_egl_api_implementation.h:66:0,
                 from /src/qt5/qtwebengine/src/core/ozone/gl_surface_qt.cpp:71:
../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings_api_autogen_egl.h:164:33: error: 'EGLDeviceEXT' has not been declared
                                 EGLDeviceEXT* devices,
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings_api_autogen_egl.h:166:13: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
 const char* eglQueryDeviceStringEXTFn(EGLDeviceEXT device,
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings_api_autogen_egl.h:166:52: error: expected ')' before 'device'
 const char* eglQueryDeviceStringEXTFn(EGLDeviceEXT device,
                                                    ^~~~~~
../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings_api_autogen_egl.h:196:36: error: 'EGLSetBlobFuncANDROID' has not been declared
                                    EGLSetBlobFuncANDROID set,
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings_api_autogen_egl.h:197:36: error: 'EGLGetBlobFuncANDROID' has not been declared
                                    EGLGetBlobFuncANDROID get) override;
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_egl_api_implementation.h:82:0,
                 from /src/qt5/qtwebengine/src/core/ozone/gl_surface_qt.cpp:71:
../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings_api_autogen_egl.h:164:33: error: 'EGLDeviceEXT' has not been declared
                                 EGLDeviceEXT* devices,
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings_api_autogen_egl.h:166:13: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
 const char* eglQueryDeviceStringEXTFn(EGLDeviceEXT device,
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings_api_autogen_egl.h:166:52: error: expected ')' before 'device'
 const char* eglQueryDeviceStringEXTFn(EGLDeviceEXT device,
                                                    ^~~~~~
../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings_api_autogen_egl.h:196:36: error: 'EGLSetBlobFuncANDROID' has not been declared
                                    EGLSetBlobFuncANDROID set,
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/gl/gl_bindings_api_autogen_egl.h:197:36: error: 'EGLGetBlobFuncANDROID' has not been declared
                                    EGLGetBlobFuncANDROID get) override;
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option '-Wno-deprecated-copy'
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option '-Wno-class-memaccess'
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option '-Wno-class-memaccess'
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option '-Wno-packed-not-aligned'
[...]
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
make[4]: *** [Makefile.gn_run:763: run_ninja] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/src/pi3/qtwebengine/src/core'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:82: sub-gn_run-pro-make_first] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/src/pi3/qtwebengine/src/core'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:79: sub-core-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/src/pi3/qtwebengine/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:49: sub-src-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/src/pi3/qtwebengine'
make: *** [Makefile:370: module-qtwebengine-make_first] Error 2
```

Comment: I was able to make it compile by removing `-opengl es2`. This is of course not desirable, as it disables OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same errors and got it working by adding 3 [symlinks](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-symbolic-links-in-linux-using-the-ln-command/):

in sysroot/opt/vc/include/EGL

```
mv egl.h egl.h-old
mv eglext.h eglext.h-old
mv eglplatform.h eglplatform.h-old

ln -s /<...>/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/khronos/EGL/eglext.h eglext.h
ln -s /<...>/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/khronos/EGL/egl.h egl.h
ln -s /<...>/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/khronos/EGL/eglplatform.h eglplatform.h
```

where <...> is the path to the qt root directory.

There are many versions of egl.h/eglext.h/eglplatform.h to include and because of the include order the comiler fetches first the files in sysroot/opt/vc/include/EGL

Perhaps a better solution would be to reorder the "-I" flags for the compiler.

i did **not**
**dpkg --purge libraspberrypi-dev**